# Copy a file from remote Windows machine to Linux machine without Cygwin

Tags: windows, copy, cygwin

I am looking for a possibility to copy a file from Windows to a Linux machine, and my Windows machine will not have Cygwin installed .

The command I am trying is

```
linux #>   scp windows-machine:e:\file.txt
```

Comment: Since you explicitly state that Windows will *not* have Cygwin installed, perhaps the `cygwin` tag should be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "my windows machine will not have cygwin installed", I'm assuming you cannot install arbitrary software on the Windows side but that you have control of the Linux machine.  Under those assumptions, you can use the Windows FTP client to transfer files to the Linux machine.  (Of course, you will have to enable the FTP daemon on the Linux machine, most likely via inetd or systemctl.)